# Gorilla Websocket: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: go, websocket, http-status-code-404, handshake, gorilla

I cloned the gorilla websocket chat example and updated it to use multiple rooms. However, I am getting the error:
`Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`
In chrome whenever I try to make the connection. My source code is available on [github](https://github.com/ibraheemdev/go-chat/tree/rooms). It is very similar to the original example, and was only changed slightly. I don't know why it is not working.

EDIT:
The problem is occuring in this line of code:

```
for _, name := range []string{"arduino", "java", "go", "scala"} {
    room := newRoom("go")
    http.Handle("/chat/go", room)
    go room.run()
}
```

Looping over a slice is causing an issue with the httphandle function. If instead, I declare them individually:

```
room := newRoom("go")
http.Handle("/chat/go", room)
go room.run()
...
```

It works. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi, I've check your code and it works https://ibb.co/y023X26. What is your OS and your Golang version?

Comment: @FahimBagar I think you got the wrong link. It is under the branch "rooms"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So actually from your `index.html` file, you connect to wrong url

```
<!-- index.html -->
<script>
    var serviceLocation = "ws://0.0.0.0:8080/chat/";
.....

    function connectToChatserver() {
        room = $('#chatroom option:selected').val();
        wsocket = new WebSocket(serviceLocation + room);
        // it connect to /chat/<room>, it has slash after chat
```

This is your url from `main.go`

```
    http.Handle("/chat"+name, room)
```

It will make url like this: http://localhost:8080/chatgo, rather than what you want: http://localhost:8080/chat/go

*Fyi*, it will error because you don't properly handle the `channel`, so after I send 1 message, it will be automatically closed. But this is another topic.

```
2020/08/04 06:42:10 running chat room java
2020/08/04 06:42:10 running chat room go
2020/08/04 06:42:10 running chat room arduino
2020/08/04 06:42:10 running chat room scala
2020/08/04 06:42:15 new client in room arduino
2020/08/04 06:42:15 client leaving room arduino
2020/08/04 06:42:15 client leaving room arduino
panic: close of closed channel

goroutine 6 [running]:
main.(*Room).run(0xc00007ac90)
        /home/fahim/Projects/Golang/go-chat/room.go:70 +0x3b5
created by main.main
        /home/fahim/Projects/Golang/go-chat/main.go:17 +0x2bd
exit status 2
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. I knew it was something silly like that :). I fixed the channel closing error. Thanks